# Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, specifications

In my project, I am trying to replace the existing entities with entities from another libraries. I a getting a weird problem with specifications, criteriabuilder and join stuff. Here I am having the following classes

```
    @Entity
@Table(
    name = "company"
)
public class RoomEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(
        name = "id"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        generator = "seq-table",
        strategy = GenerationType.TABLE
    )
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "parentCompany",
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    orphanRemoval = false
)
private Set<RoomHierarchyEntity> children;
```

2

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "room_hierarchy"
)
public class RoomHierarchyEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(
        name = "id"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        generator = "seq-table",
        strategy = GenerationType.TABLE
    )
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        optional = false
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "parent_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
    name = "fk_Roomhierarchy_p_room"
)
    )
    private RoomEntity parentRoom;
    @ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        optional = false
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "child_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
    name = "fk_Roomhierarchy_c_room"
)
    )
    private RoomEntity childRoom;
    @Column(
        name = "distance",
        nullable = false
    )
    private Integer distance;
```

3

```
public class ResourceEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(
        name = "id"
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        generator = "seq-table",
        strategy = GenerationType.TABLE
    )
    private Long id;
    @Column(
        name = "room_id",
        nullable = false
    )
    @NotNull
    private Integer RoomId;

)
```

Service1.java

```
findByCompanyAnd(ResEntity.class, roomId);
```

Service2.java

```
public static <T> Specifications<T> findByRoomAnd(Class<T> queryClass, Integer companyId,
                                                                            ) {
    return findByCompany(queryClass, companyId));

}
```

SpecificationsUtil.Java

```
public static <T> Specifications<T> findByCompany(Class<T> queryClass, Integer companyId) {
    return findByCompany(queryClass, companyId, COLUMNS.get(queryClass));
}


private static <T> Specifications<T> findByRoom(final Class<T> queryClass, final Integer RoomId,
                                                                             final Set<String> columnNames) {
       return Specifications.where(new Specification<T>() {
           @Override
           public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
               Join<RoomEntity, RoomHierarchyEntity> chRoot = root.join("room").join("children");

               Subquery<Integer> sq = query.subquery(Integer.class);
               Root<T> sqRoot = sq.from(queryClass);
               Join<CompanyEntity, CompanyHierarchyEntity> sqChRoot = sqRoot.join("room").join("children");
               sq.select(sqChRoot.<Integer>get("distance"));

               ...
           }
       });
   }
```

The difference between old ResEntity and new ResEntity is that, old one has entity RoomEntity as an object where as new one just has RoomId in it. I am getting a variety of errors when I put the new type of ResEntity.

I am getting error at

```
Join<RoomEntity, RoomHierarchyEntity> chRoot = root.join("room").join("children");


Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [children] on this ManagedType
```

How do I join the incoming entity (ResEntity) with RoomEntity and RoomHierarchy entity ?

Above code is the legacy one and I really don't understand what it does. I just want to join those tables and I want to run those with out disturbing things.

Answer (score 0):

You changed entities and now there are no fields `room`, `children`.
Now you cannot use `root.join("room")` because it relation does not exists. If you want to join them (inside one query) revert our changes in ResourceEntity.